# Java memory leaks with classes

Tags: java, memory-leaks, multi-layer

I am wondering if the following piece of code is a memory leak, since Google is only turning up weird examples. Basically, if I have a class `Tree`:

```
public class Tree{

     private Bird[] birds;

     public Tree(){
          birds = new Bird[100];
     }

}
```

and I hold a class reference to a `Tree` like this:

```
Tree myTree = new Tree();
```

and then shortly afterwards I set that reference to `null`:

```
myTree = null;
```

**Will all the 100 allocated Birds be taken care of WITH the tree class by the garbage collector?** Or do I need a `delete()` method? I know Java doesn't have destructors but still this multi-layer class example confuses me:

inside `Tree.java`:

```
public void deleteBirds{
     birds = null;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Will all the 100 allocated Birds be taken care of WITH the tree class by the garbage collector?

Well, your code doesn't actually create any instances of `Bird`. It just creates an array, and every element of that array will be `null` to start with.

However, the basic answer is "yes" - if you nothing else has a reference to the array, and nothing else has a reference to any of the `Bird` objects that you might create elsewhere, then the garbage collector will take care of them. You almost certainly *shouldn't* write any kind of "delete" method.

You probably don't need your `myTree = null;` statement either... if it's a local variable going out of scope, or an instance variable in an object which is going to become eligible for garbage collection anyway, then it's pointless.

It can take a while for relatively new Java programmers to learn to trust the garbage collector, and let go of control... but once you do so, your code will be a lot simpler :)

Comment: Yeah It's sort of difficult sometimes to trust the garbage collector when you are coming out from C++. Thanks!